# Restoring New Postgres Database with Old Data Directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have not made a backup from my old data directory, but I still have the directory in tact. In my current database I have the same Schema, etc... When I try to restore the database (using pgadmin III), I receive this error:

```
/Applications/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_restore --host localhost -- port 5432 -- username "postgres" --dbname "postgres" --role "postgres" --no-password --format directory --verbose "/Library/Postgres/9.5/data" 
pg_restore: [directory archiver] could not open input file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/toc.dat": No such file or directory
```

I am not sure where the toc.dat came into play, as I am not familiar with it. This is evidently halting the restore, but I do not know how to fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

while restoring don't use --format in arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Using **3.0 version** of **pgAdmin 4**

Might be too late, but this works for me all the time.

**From the Current or Old database**

1. Launch pgAdmin;
2. Expand Servers and login therein;
3. Expand PostgreSQL, and then click the name of the database that you want to export/Backup;
4. Right click on it for options and select `Backup...`;
5. On the opened window, Enter a suitable `filename` and make sure `format` is set to **Tar** from the drop-down menu;
6. Then Click Backup on the bottom;

Once the Backup file is saved

**On the New or Other database**(Or on a different machine)

Create a new database and right click on it once created, select `Restore...` option and locate the `Backup` up file created earlier. *You might have to have select*

> `Show hidden files and folders`
>   option and set 
>   `Format` to `All Files`

That error should not be experienced with this method.